# Reverting to the default icon of the Trash bin

Tags: gnome, icons, trash

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME). I have just changed the default icon of the Trash bin to a custom one by right-clicking the trash bin icon, choosing properties, clicking on the old icon and finding the new corresponding icon file via Nautilus. No terminal commands were used.

Now I'm trying to revert the changes, but with no luck so far. Unfortunately, there's no working option like "revert changes" or something like that.

Comment: how did you change it?

Comment: Just by right-clicking the trash bin icon, choosing properties, clicking on the old icon and finding the new corresponding icon file via Nautilus. No terminal commands used. Unfortunatelly, there´s no working option like "revert changes" or something like that...

Comment: Ok.. did you install Unity?? 18.04 default uses GNOME..

Comment: Please note that to add extra important info, you need to [edit] your question and add to it (I've done it for you this time). Comments section is not a good place for important details as comments tend to get overlooked (and even deleted) easily.

Comment: Does disabling the Trash icon and enabling again work? To test this first run the following command in Terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false`, then run `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible true`.

Comment: @MartinKulle i have tried my best but without success.. there is one clue which is metadata.. particularly the icons on desktop, if we change the icon manually it is automatically generating its metadata in `~/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata` i did not get further..

Comment: @MartinKulle my bad.. from Feb 19th to 24th, i was trying to edit and save the file in a normal way.. today i could save the edits with the command `sudo -H gedit ~/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata`

Answer (score 1):

when the trash icon is changed by right clicking it, Properties and clicking on icon,

the path of this newly selected icon will be saved in `~/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata`

[image]

when the icon was not changed, some of the content in this file is

```
[trash]
nautilus-icon-position-timestamp=1551022571
nautilus-icon-position=56,146
icon-scale=1
```

for example:

I have changed the trash-icon by right clicking... then the content of above mentioned file changed to

```
[trash]
nautilus-icon-position-timestamp=1551022571
nautilus-icon-position=56,146
icon-scale=1
custom-icon=file:///home/pratap/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202019-02-24%2021-09-32.png
```

[image]

to revert the changes..
the below line need to be deleted from the file `~/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata`

```
custom-icon=file:///home/pratap/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202019-02-24%2021-09-32.png
```

to delete the line and save the changes..run the below command, edit and save the file.

```
sudo -H gedit ~/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata
```

Now logout and login to see the change..

[image]