# Further customizations -- top bar and desktop icons

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, icon-themes, top-bar

Bit of a general question here. Is it possible in Ubuntu 18.04 to move things around on the top bar? For example, the date and time in the center -- can it be moved to the right to sit next to the network and power icons? Is this only possible on what I've read is called a "Unity" desktop? (sorry if it's a silly question, quite new to Ubuntu still).

Also, is it possible to use any icon one likes for things like the Trash bin on the desktop? For instance, I have an icon theme installed, but I don't like the Trash icon, could I use the icon from Gnome or Humanity for it instead if I wanted to?

Comment: Too broad, you should ask one question per post. This is for the first query: Possible duplicate of [How do I move clock to the right end of GNOME 3 Panel from the middle?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960597/how-do-i-move-clock-to-the-right-end-of-gnome-3-panel-from-the-middle)

Comment: Ah OK, thanks @pomsky, that does answer the first part of my question.

Comment: @Adrain https://askubuntu.com/q/1118920/739431

Comment: Thanks for the links guys.

Comment: @Adrian Unity was a bad Desktop environement we used to have, trust me you don't want it. but we're in the process of getting back to the levl of customisability we used to have. maybe in the meantime, stick with kubuntu. it uses the KDE desktop environement wich is incredibly customisable.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button instead of editing old one.